# Checking length of string in an admin area field onblur with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a custom field (I use Advanced Custom Fields plugin) set up to display when creating a new Post. A user must enter a 4 digit year. No more than 4 characters, no less. I have the following in my functions.php code:

```
function make_year_created_equal_4_chars_init(){
  wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
function make_year_created_equal_4_chars() {
  echo "<script type='text/javascript'>\n";
  echo "
      jQuery('#acf-field-artwork_created').blur(function() {
      selected = jQuery('#acf-field-artwork_created').length;
        if (selected != 4) {
            alert( 'A 4 digit year must be entered in the Artwork Created field' );
        }
    });
";
echo "</script>\n"; 
}
add_action('admin_init', 'make_year_created_equal_4_chars_init');
add_action('edit_form_advanced', 'make_year_created_equal_4_chars');
add_action('edit_page_form', 'make_year_created_equal_4_chars');
```

And here is my markup:

```
<input type="text" id="acf-field-artwork_created" class="text" name="fields[field_52e10c7db579e]" placeholder="" />
```

In all respects except one, this works just fine. I have no JS errors being reported and sure enough if I enter less than 4 or more than 4 characters, as soon as I leave the field (onblur) then the error alert is triggered.

My problem is that it still triggers even if I use 4 characters.

Any help gratefully received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of issues with your code but most importantly you need to call `val` on the text input. Here is how your `make_year_created_equal_4_chars` function might look:

```
function make_year_created_equal_4_chars() {
?>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    // This is a shorthand for "jQuery(document).ready()"
    jQuery(function($) { 
        $('#acf-field-artwork_created').blur(function() {
            // Please notice the declaration of 'selected_length'.
            // It is important to declare it with 'var' so that
            // you don't end up with it in the global scope.
            var selected_length = $(this).val().length;

            if (selected_length != 4) {
                alert( 'A 4 digit year must be entered in the Artwork Created field' );
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<?php
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that works perfectly. Seems I need to do some more reading!